# Rendering AngularJS directives from array of directive names in a parent directive or controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to dynamically render directives based on a configuration array of directive names.  Is this possible in angular?  I also want these rendered directives to live within a single parent dom element rather than each getting a new wrapper (as you would with ng-repeat)

http://jsfiddle.net/7Waxv/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('one', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div>Directive one</div>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('two', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div>Directive two</div>'
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.directives = ['one', 'two'];
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="directive in directives">
        <div {{directive}}></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Since posting this, I've also tried:

```
.directive('parentDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.directives = ['one', 'two'];
      for (var i = 0; i < scope.directives.length; i++) { 
        element.prepend('<div ' + scope.directives[i] + '></div>')
      }
    }
  };
});

<div parent-directive></div>
```

With this, the templates from the prepended directives are not rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here what I came up with (took a long time)... The solution is pretty versatile though, you can modify `$scope.directives` array at will and the directives will be fabricated dynamically. You can also point to any particular property in the current scope to retrieve the directive list from.

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/7Waxv/2/)

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('one', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Directive one</div>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('two', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Directive two</div>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('dynamic', function ($compile, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      attr.$observe('dynamic', function(val) {
        element.html('');
        var directives = $parse(val)(scope);
        angular.forEach(directives, function(directive) {
          element.append($compile(directive)(scope));
        });
      });
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.directives = ['<one/>', '<two/>'];
    $scope.add = function(directive) {
        $scope.directives.push(directive);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div dynamic="{{directives}}"></div>
    <button ng-click="add('<one/>')">Add One</button>
    <button ng-click="add('<two/>')">Add One</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than use `element.append`, did you think about setting `restrict: 'C'` and updating the class on the element? This way the directive can be added to existing dom elements or when creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

So the second attempt would have worked had I used $compile on the prepended directives like so:

```
.directive('parentDirective', function($compile)
    ....
element.prepend($compile('<div ' + scope.directives[i] + '"></div>')(scope));
```